# iOS 11 custom navigation bar gives two bars

Tags: ios

When I try to add a custom UINavigationBar to a view controller like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    static let nav_bar_height: CGFloat = 64

    let nav_bar: UINavigationBar =
    {
        let nav_bar = UINavigationBar()
        nav_bar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        nav_bar.backgroundColor = .blue
        return nav_bar
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        view.addSubview(nav_bar)
        nav_bar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: ViewController.nav_bar_height).isActive = true
        nav_bar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        nav_bar.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        nav_bar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).isActive = true

    }
}
```

two distinct bars show up. 
[image]

Any idea on why there is the white colored bar with a smaller height?

This is the AppDelegate

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        let vc = ViewController()
        window?.rootViewController = vc
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably in navigation interface with a UINavigationController as your view controller's parent.

So the second navigation bar is the UINavigationController's navigation bar.

Comment: Also, the way you are positioning and sizing your navigation bar is not how you do it. But we can deal with that after you finish grappling with the surrounding navigation controller interface.

Comment: But there is no navigation controller interface. `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        let vc = ViewController()
        window?.rootViewController = vc
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
`

Comment: So you claim. But I bet there's stuff you are concealing. I think you have a storyboard you're not telling us about, and I think that the initial view controller in your storyboard _is_ a navigation controller (with a ViewController as its root view controller), and _that_ is the view controller that is being loaded. The second navigation bar is merely diagnostic of that issue.

Comment: I deleted the story board though. Why don't you copy the above code in swift 4 xcode Version 9.0 (9A235) and see what you get?

Comment: Because I’m not having any problem (and your code for positioning the navigation bar is wrong, as I already said, so I would never do that). I already know how to show a navigation bar, and I don’t get two of them.  _You’re_ the one causing this to happen, in some way you have not described. That’s why I have to guess. Why don’t _you_ put an example project on github or similar so I can download it and see what you’re doing wrong?